# "which" or "who" after "the work of somebody,"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In the sentence "We refer to the work of Alice and Bob, [] proposed a novel idea of ......". Which word should I use in [], "which" or "who"?

Thanks.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's ambiguous. The relative pronoun could refer to "the work" or "Alice and Bob", but more likely to the whole "the work of Alice and Bob".

Comment: Who or what proposed the novel idea? Alice and Bob, or their work? Without knowing that, it's impossible to say which word you should use. They are both grammatical, but they provide a different meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Which"** is the correct word.

"Which" is used to refer to things, whereas "who" is used to refer to people.

In this case, we are referring to the **works** of Alice and Bob, *which* is a **thing.**

Comment: That's only assuming you're referring to their works. You could also easily be referring to the people, in which case *who* works. (Alice and Bob proposed a novel idea …) *Which* would only be mandated if the comma were followed by *in*, but it isn't. Without that syntactical cue, there is no way of knowing if the word should be *which* or *who*, unless the author of the sentence indicates the meaning they wanted to convey. Only the second sentence of your answer is unambiguously correct. They other two sentence might or might not be correct, but there's no way for you to know that.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, the sentence says: "We refer to the work of Alice and Bob..."  They are quite clearly referring to the work, not the people.  If you were reading the sentence, you could interpret it either way.  However, the OP is writing it, so they are clearly talking about the work, not the people.

Comment: That part of the sentence does, but only when nothing else follows it. If you add the rest of the sentence, using ***who*** is entirely grammatical, and it changes what is being referred to. If I write *who proposed*, I am clearly ***not*** talking about the work, but the people. The question says nothing either way about who or what is being talked about, so you are making an unsubstantiated assumption that it is one rather than the other.

Comment: @JasonBassford You are right that both are grammatical and would make sense, but it is *most likely* that the OP wants to talk about the works in the second half of the sentence (yes, it is an assumption).